# Why does running this not issue a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory, gcc, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid read/write sometimes creates segmentation fault and sometimes does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641478/invalid-read-write-sometimes-creates-segmentation-fault-and-sometimes-does-not)

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (ptr) {
        *ptr = 10;
        printf("sizeof(int): %zu\nsizeof(char): %zu\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(char));
        printf("deref of ptr: %d\n", *ptr);
        free(ptr);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

When I compile and run it, I get following output:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof(int): 4
sizeof(char): 1
deref of ptr: 10
```

The value `sizeof(char)` is less than `sizeof(int)`. My `malloc` call only sets aside enough space for a `char`. Yet, my program is able to assign an integer value to `ptr` without crashing. Why does this work?

Comment: You might want to look at this question and its answers for guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641478/invalid-read-write-sometimes-creates-segmentation-fault-and-sometimes-does-not

Comment: C will not necessarily respect the variable 'boundries', so you're likely overwriting some random 3 bytes in memory that happen to follow the one you allocated.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (6.5.3.4, §3).

Comment: I know that `sizeof(char)` is always 1. I was just trying this out to determine the basic principles at work.

Comment: The wonderful thing about invoking undefined behaviour is that anything can happen and it is "OK" - the required behaviour is undefined.

Comment: If you have answers, I'd appreciate it if you please try to add them as answers and not comments.

Comment: If you leave a downvote, please take the time to comment why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because you are writing into unallocated memory does not mean the program will crash. There is no runtime bounds checking like that.

The segfault will occur when you are accessing memory out of the address range allocated through the operating system as detected by the hardware. You may get away with a lot of memory access before then in your heap.

Answer (score 6):

Writing to a too-small buffer is undefined behavior. There is no guarentee that it will crash. It might not crash. It might appear to work. It might also corrupt some data silently. It might cause your program to do something unintended - many security holes come from this, when an attacker manipulates the effect of undefined behavior into something undesired. By a strict reading of a standard, this might even have the effect of summoning demons from your nose.

At an architectural level, usually allocations are rounded up to some power of two (but this is not guaranteed by any means!), hence why you didn't see anything obviously untoward here. But *do not rely on this*, as it can and does vary.

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` implementations can, and often will, allocate a bit more memory than you asked for. Most implementations will round up to the nearest multiple of 8 or 16 bytes, at a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware memory managers control complete memory pages, often 4K.  Unless your write overflows a page boundary, the memory management hardware will not generate a SEGFAULT/Access Violation interrupt.

Your example 'works' because one element of the large set of 'undefined behavior' is 'appearing to work correctly, at least for now'.  If you add complexity to your app, other members of the set will appear...

Answer (score 1):

This works accidentally.  Your malloc likely allocates a chunk significantly larger than a single character (usually because tracking nanoscopic pieces isn't worth the overhead).  So you are likely tromping outside the space you are supposed to have, but it doesn't matter in your implementation.

Your program is still erroneous, I think, according to the standard.  And if it were much bigger, and you made that mistake in places where it didn't work accidentally, you'd get all kinds of bad behavior, sometimes an illegal memory access, but sometimes just completely crazy behavior because you can damage your or system data structures.

Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) test tool should be able to spot this error; technically, you're storing outside the area you requested, and that's detectable with enough effort.